# Can NOT run Matlab controller

Tags: matlab

despite all the effort that I have made still receive the error:

> WARNING: nao_matlab: failed to start: matlab  -nosplash -nodesktop -r
>   launcher
>
> WARNING: Unable to find the 'matlab' executable in the current PATH.
>   Please check your matlab installation. It should be possible to launch
>   matlab from a terminal by typing 'matlab'. It may be necessary to add
>   the matlab bin directory to your PATH environment variable. More
>   information about the matlab installation is available in Webots' User
>   guide.

I have installed the Xcode

I have tried `brew gcc command line`
also I have used the Webot user guide

but still nothing

and OS: macOS Catalina

does anyone have any idea what should I do to solve the error?!!!

Comment: Have you tried what the message asked you to do? Check the path variable!

Comment: Yeah the problem is it exists there but still it can NOT find it... any suggestions?!!